# git clone creates fork on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Recently I came across a GitHub discussion post in which the author says:

> When I do something like this:
>
> ```
> git clone hogehoge  # a repository which I only have Read access
> touch test.txt
> git add .
> git commit -m 'test'
> gh pr create  # make a PR
> ```
>
> It turned out that a fork is automatically created and any of my local branches are set up to track the fork, instead of the original repo.

To which another user replies:

> Correct, that is in fact how the git clone command works, this excerpt is taken from the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_description) on git clone.

The line in the documentation that he is referring to states:

> Clones a repository into a newly created directory, creates remote-tracking branches for each branch in the cloned repository (visible using git branch --remotes), and creates and checks out an initial branch ***that is forked from the cloned repository’s currently active branch***.

Here is a link to the original discussion: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/22665

I wanted to check that this was true, so I cloned a repository that I do not have read/write access to. Upon cloning and checking GitHub, no new fork had been created. I tried changing a file on my local machine and pushing it to the remote repository which lead to git telling me that I do not have the necessary permissions, indicating that I am not on a forked repository. From here I'm sure I would have to manually fork through GitHub and then relink the remote to my new fork if I really wanted to modify the file.

Although my intention wasn't actually to change anything about the repository I cloned, I noticed that the behavior described in the discussion did not occur on my end and was wondering why. The post was made about three years ago, so it doesn't seem like anything this massive would have changed since then, although I could be wrong. Additionally, I noticed that the user who made the post used the "gh pr create" command, so they must be using the GitHub CLI. Does the GitHub CLI include this additional functionality for cloning?

Comment: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/35849 says fork must be done explicitly from the web UI when using git, while github desktop fork automatically for a repo without write access https://docs.github.com/en/desktop/contributing-and-collaborating-using-github-desktop/adding-and-cloning-repositories/cloning-and-forking-repositories-from-github-desktop. I tried the Github CLI and merely cloning doesn't automatically create a fork. Not planning to test with create empty PR because I've seen at least a couple of such PR polluting my public repo

Comment: There's a mismatch between the GitHub definition of "fork" (create a new repo from this point) and what the Git documentation is using there (create a new branch from this point).

Comment: @Martheen Thank you for trying out the GitHub CLI, as well as the information about GitHub Desktop.

Comment: @JimRedmond I could see that being the case, but the user says, "... and any of my local branches are set up to track the fork, instead of the original repo." Doesn't this imply that an actual GitHub fork was created?

Comment: Not if they're actually using vanilla `git clone` like they said. The remote URL (`git remote -v`) would be the authoritative answer, though - is it the same as the original repo, or has it changed somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the answer was indeed in the GitHub CLI. However, it wasn't the `git clone` command that creates the fork, but rather in the `gh pr create` command. The GitHub CLI documentation for the `gh pr create` command states:

> This command will automatically create a fork for you if you're in a repository that you don't have permission to push to.

Here is the documentation page: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create